# How can i return all the results from my array?

Tags: php, foreach

```
Array 
( 
    [edit] => true 
    [id] => 1 
    [type] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => LC 
    ) 
    [userid] => 1 
    [norooms] => 1 
    [park] => Central 
    [start] => 09:00 
    [end] => 11:00 
    [length] => 2 
    [student] => 79 
    [status] => Rejected  
)
```

```
<?php
$posted_data = array();
if (!empty($_POST['edit'])) {
   $posted_data = json_decode($_POST['editVal'], true);
}
print_r ($posted_data);

foreach ($posted_data as $key => $value) {
    echo '<p>'.$key.'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$value.'</p>';
}
?>
```

The array at the top is the `jason_decode` returned. However with my `foreach` function it does not display the first index of the array within the array. ie. `( [0] => LC )`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The answers provided are good if you are wanting to display the array to a user and need the ability to format the html... but if you are simply wanting to look at the array for debugging purposes, check out print_r and/or var_dump.

Answer (score 3):

You need to build a recursive function, something like:

```
function print_recursively(array $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            print_recursively($value);
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<p>'.$key.'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$value.'</p>';
        }
    } 
}
```

Tune it according to your needs.

Comment: Wow, that's more like dynamic.. ! I gave the solution for 1 level only..!!

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo ehehe yes, I always prefer dynamic functions and methods (in order to adapt to different situations), but it's just a matter of personal preferences! :)

Comment: that's recursive. I have used recursion and that best fits the problem statement here..!

Comment: plus one for dynamic approach

Answer (score 2):

If you know there is array hierarchy to one level only

Keep printing the values and if the value is an array using `is_array`.. Iterate again.

```
  foreach($dataArray as $key =>$value){ 
  if(is_array($value)){
     foreach($value as $array2Data){
           echo  $array2Data; //you can use keys as well
      }
  }
  else 
      echo $value;
  }
```